# Laravel: Conditional Eloquent query (Today, Month & Year)

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have many queries that I must repeat, since they depend on the choice of a filter obtained through a Select (Today, Month & Year), which shows the corresponding information in the ranges specified above: Current Day, Current Month and Year Current.

Here is the code:

```
if ($filterDashboardMerchant == 'month'){
    // Total Revenue || Month
    $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
        ->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month)
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
        ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
        ->get();
    }
else{
    if($filterDashboardMerchant == 'year'){
        // Total Revenue || Year
        $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
            ->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year)
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
            ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
            ->get();
    else{
        // Total Revenue || Today
        $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
            ->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day)
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
            ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Given that all the query code is the same and only 3 of the conditions are different within them:

```
->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month)

->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year)

->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day)
```

How could only that condition change in the same code snippet, dependent on the choice in the Select that filters to them ?

It would be of great help to me, as this is just less than 5% of what I have developed and it would save me a lot of code.

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? Else i'm glad to try to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a `when()` query method, that only executes a given callback if a condition is true. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

```
AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
    ->when($filterDashboardMerchant === 'day', function ($query) {
        $query->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day);
    })
    ->when($filterDashboardMerchant === 'month', function ($query) {
        $query->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month);
    }) 
    ->when($filterDashboardMerchant === 'year', function ($query) {
        $query->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year);
    })
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
    ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
    ->get();
```

For a more clean approach scopes can be used, add the scope in your `AffiliateOrder.php` class.

```
public function scopeFilterAffiliates($query, $filter) {
    $query->join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
        ->when($filter === 'day', function ($query) {
            $query->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day);
        })
        ->when($filter === 'month', function ($query) {
            $query->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month);
        }) 
        ->when($filter === 'year', function ($query) {
            $query->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year);
        })
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
        ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id);
}
```

Now you can use the scope like so.

```
AffiliateOrder::filterAffiliates($filterDashboardMerchant)
    ->get();
```